want to subtract two dates which are in string format in pandas dataframe in python
I have one data frame which has two date colums. but the dates are in string datatype. I am trying to convert them into panda datetime format to substract from each other. but i am getting the error. Can i get some help?
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'date1' : ['30-May-2024','30-May-2024','30-May-2024'],'date2' : ['20-May-2024','20-May-2024','10-May-2024']})

result date1-date2:
10   10  20

I tried doing following but it is giving me error.
pd.to_datetime((df1['date1'])).date() - pd.to_datetime((df1['date2'])).date()

ERROR:  time data "30-May-2024" doesn't match format "%d-%B-%Y", at position 1.


For me working well solution df1['days']  = (pd.to_datetime(df1['date1']).sub(pd.to_datetime(df1['date2']))).dt.days

it is not forking for 27-Jun-2024. Any idea?

Yop, Jun is not in English, so failed. What is language used there?

what do you mean not in english?

It means Jun in English is June, so it is reason for fail

but it take only 3 letters in a month

hmmm, I test print (pd.to_datetime('27-Jun-2024')) and ouput is 2024-06-27 00:00:00, what is your pandas version? Is possible upgrade?

okay let me try
